# ng-repeat errors. Can't read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two errors saying: `Cannot read property 'active' of undefined` and `Cannot read property 'boss' of undefined` while I'm trying to use `ng-repeat` over my array of users.

In the controller I'm using the following code:

```
            $scope.users = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'John',
                birthday: '06.07.2008',
                city: 'Budapest',
                active: false,
                boss: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Mary',
                birthday: '01.02.2003',
                city: 'Berlin',
                active: false,
                boss: true
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'James',
                birthday: '04.05.2006',
                city: 'Vienna',
                active: false,
                boss: false
            }
        ];

        $scope.isActive = function (id) {
            return $scope.users[id].active;
        }

        $scope.isBoss = function (id) {
            console.log($scope.users[id]);
            return $scope.users[id].boss;
        }
```

In the view I have following code:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Boss</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <div>
            <tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.birthday}}</td>
                <td>{{user.city}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{ checked: isActive(user.id) }">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="boss" ng-checked="{ checked: isBoss(user.id) }">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </tbody>
```

At the end it prints the table in the right way but also throws those errors. Did I miss something?

Also here's rendered result:

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: user in users -->
    <tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">1</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">John</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">06.07.2008</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Budapest</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{ checked: isActive(user.id) }" checked="checked">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="boss" ng-checked="{ checked: isBoss(user.id) }" checked="checked">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: user in users -->
    <tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">2</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Mary</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">01.02.2003</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Berlin</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{ checked: isActive(user.id) }" checked="checked">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="boss" ng-checked="{ checked: isBoss(user.id) }" checked="checked">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: user in users -->
    <tr ng-click="goToProfile(user.id)" ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">3</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">James</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">04.05.2006</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Vienna</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="active" ng-checked="{ checked: isActive(user.id) }">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="boss" ng-checked="{ checked: isBoss(user.id) }">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: user in users -->

</tbody>
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add a different question;  if this question was answered, you should accept the answer and open a new question with the new issue (referencing this question if necessary).  Changing the fundamental question in a thread makes it very difficult for future readers to identify which answer solved which problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `isActive` and `isBoss` functions are being passed `user.id`. I observed your `user.id` starts from id 1, meanwhile in these functions, you're trying to access the `$scope.users` using the indexes passed in. What happens is that, for example, a `user.id` of 3 in your `isActive` function would try to access `$scope.users[3].active`. However, there's actually no index 3 (representing the fourth item in the `$scope.users` array, which is `undefined`)

Change your `..isActive(user.id)` to `...isActive($index)` and your `...isBoss(user.id)` to `...isBoss($index)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've done editing on the post added some bugs I have aftermath. Take a look will you.

Comment: You should open another issue for the update. It's unrelated to the initial question